# How to recover deleted Xcode project?

Tags: xcode

I have accidentally moved my xcode project to trash and than cleared the trash.
Is there any way to find it back, or even some files that will be useful?

Answer (score 1):

Use time machine or your system backup, or check your project out from source control again. If you're not using any of those things, you've just learnt why they are a good idea.

You might find answers on Ask Different, but general questions about recovering deleted files are off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

In general your question is how to recover files deleted from trash. Look [this discussion](http://discussions.apple.com/thread/4070374) on apple support community. Hope this will help you.

This is quote:

> **General File Recovery**
>   If you stop using the drive it's possible to
>   recover deleted files that have not been overwritten by using recovery
>   software such as Data Rescue II, File Salvage or TechTool Pro.  Each
>   of the preceding come on bootable CDs to enable usage without risk of
>   writing more data to the hard drive.  Two free alternatives are Disk
>   Drill and TestDisk.  Look for them and demos at MacUpdate or CNET
>   Downloads.

Comment: Be careful with disk drill. I payed $89 for disk drill which didn't work, then the company said it's my own fault for purchasing it without predicting whether the recovery would be successful. Buyer Beware.